Athena try_cast is not returning null
I have below query
SELECT * from table WHERE TRY_CAST(date as varchar) is null

as per my understanding ,TRY_CAST return null if it is not able to cast, it should return those rows having date column any invalid data, but I am getting below error

INVALID_FUNCTION_ARGUMENT: Invalid format: "found the very best underwear!"

In data there is no column with this value
not able to understand this why getting this error
Thanks,

Did you intend to run TRY_CAST(date as varchar) or TRY_CAST(data as varchar) ?

it has date column

How are you running your code?  Maybe your calling app or tool is getting fed some exception.

I am running the query in aws athena console itself

You should post the real query and some sample data (your table isn't called table).

What is the return of select typeof(date)? Also was not able to repro, returns null for me. Possibly you have meant trycast(date as date) or  trycast(date as timestamp). Also please show the code resulting in the error.

data type of date is date, I have also tried with some other dataset and it was working, but don't know why this is not working with this, I have main concern regarding the error , because the error it showing , that value is not in the dataset in any column


data type of date is date

Then highly likely that the error means that the connector/store/file has data which is not a valid date and error happens when reading the data from the store and converting it to the date, which happens before the try_cast and etc.
Just selecting the column should result in the same behavior.
Casting to varchar should be supported for any date and try_cast does not make much sense here.
Options:

change the type of date to varchar
fix the data

